# How to fetch the latest status from a table of Updates and join it with table of details in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

The two tables that I am using are:

```
CREATE TABLE `UPDATE_TABLE` (
    `DETAIL_ID` VARCHAR(10), 
    `UPDATE_ID` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
    `STATUS` ENUM('COMPLETE','INCOMPLETE') NOT NULL, 
    `UPDATED_ON` DATETIME NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`UPDATE_ID`), 
    FOREIGN KEY(`DETAIL_ID`) REFERENCES `TASK_DETAIL` (`DETAIL_ID`)
);

CREATE TABLE `DETAIL_TABLE` (
    `DETAIL_ID` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    `NAME` VARCHAR(50), 
);
```

I need the details: DETAIL_ID, NAME, STATUS (Latest), UPDATED_ON in my final result.
What I am currently doing is:

SELECT t.* FROM update_table t WHERE UPDATED_ON in (
SELECT MAX(UPDATED_ON) as latest_update FROM update_table group by DETAIL_ID
) to fetch the details of the latest updates, and do a left join on detail_table.

But the problem comes when multiple detail_ids have the same updated_on.
For Eg:

```
UPDATE_TABLE:
100,    1,  INCOMPLETE  2021-04-03 17:03:34
200,    2,  INCOMPLETE  2021-04-03 17:03:34
300,    3,  INCOMPLETE  2021-04-03 17:03:34
200,    4,  COMPLETE    2021-04-04 11:50:41
```

So this gives me 2 updates of detail_id = 200.
I need only the latest update.

A SQLAlchemy Query would be a great bonus!

Comment: How do you define the "latest update" if the date/time column has the same values?  Remember:  SQL tables are *unordered*.  As further confusion, you define the first column as a primary key yet the first column in your example has duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If UPDATED_ON field on UPDATE_TABLE never has same value for 1 DETAIL_ID then this should be work for your case

```
CREATE TABLE `UPDATE_TABLE` (
    `DETAIL_ID` VARCHAR(10), 
    `UPDATE_ID` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
    `STATUS` ENUM('COMPLETE','INCOMPLETE') NOT NULL, 
    `UPDATED_ON` DATETIME NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`UPDATE_ID`)
);

Insert into `UPDATE_TABLE` values('100','1','INCOMPLETE','2021-04-03 17:03:34');
Insert into `UPDATE_TABLE` values('200','2','INCOMPLETE','2021-04-03 17:03:34');
Insert into `UPDATE_TABLE` values('300','3','INCOMPLETE','2021-04-03 17:03:34');
Insert into `UPDATE_TABLE` values('200','4','COMPLETE','2021-04-04 11:50:41');
```

| DETAIL_ID | UPDATE_ID | STATUS | UPDATED_ON |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 | INCOMPLETE | 2021-04-03 17:03:34 |
| 200 | 2 | INCOMPLETE | 2021-04-03 17:03:34 |
| 300 | 3 | INCOMPLETE | 2021-04-03 17:03:34 |
| 200 | 4 | COMPLETE | 2021-04-04 11:50:41 |

Here is what you need:

```
select ut.*
from `UPDATE_TABLE` ut
inner join (select detail_id, max(updated_on) as 'updated_on'
            from `UPDATE_TABLE`
            group by detail_id) tbl 
            on ut.detail_id = tbl.detail_id and ut.updated_on = tbl.updated_on
order by detail_id
```

result:

| DETAIL_ID | UPDATE_ID | STATUS | UPDATED_ON |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 | INCOMPLETE | 2021-04-03 17:03:34 |
| 200 | 4 | COMPLETE | 2021-04-04 11:50:41 |
| 300 | 3 | INCOMPLETE | 2021-04-03 17:03:34 |

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1cc2fb295362a9911e0ca30527da5aa1)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below SQL query to get the results you need:
SELECT distinct(ut.DETAIL_ID), dt.NAME, ut.STATUS, ut.UPDATED_ON
FROM UPDATE_TABLE ut, DETAIL_TABLE dt
WHERE ut.DETAIL_ID = dt.DETAIL_ID
AND ut.UPDATED_ON = (SELECT MAX(UPDATED_ON) FROM UPDATE_TABLE WHERE DETAIL_ID = ut.DETAIL_ID);

Comment: This is exactly what is not giving me the correct output as for detail_id = 200 I am getting 2 statuses because Max(UPDATED_ON) = 2021-04-03 17:03:34 as well as 2021-04-04 11:50:41

Comment: I have updated the query slightly. And as far as getting 2 statuses are concerned, I have added a where clause to the subquery which will always return the max UPDATED_ON value for each particular DETAIL_ID.